# How to solve for $y(x)$ if $\sin^2(x)y'/\sqrt{(\sin(x)y')^2 + 1} = C$?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I would like to solve for $y(x)$ given that (for some constant C):

$$ \frac{\sin^2(x)y'}{\sqrt{(\sin(x)y')^2 + 1}} = C$$

I thought one thing I could do something like:

\begin{align*}
&\quad \frac{\sin^2(x)y'}{\sqrt{(\sin(x)y')^2 + 1}} = C \\
&\equiv \sin^2(x)y'= C\sqrt{(\sin(x)y')^2 + 1} \\
&\equiv \sin^4(x)y'^2 = C\left(\sin^2(x)y'^2 + 1\right) \\
&\equiv (y')^2 = \frac{C}{\sin^4(x) - C\sin^2(x)} \\
&\implies y' = \pm \sqrt{\frac{C}{\sin^4(x) - C\sin^2(x)}}
\end{align*}

Does the last step make sense? It doesn't really make sense to me. Do I have two ODEs for the same function? Two ODEs defining different parts of the same function? Is there a way to avoid the whole $\pm$ deal with a nice substitution?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at your
original equation.
If $C > 0$
and
you use the
positive square root,
this implies that
$y' > 0$.

You introduced the
possible negative $y'$
when you squared it.

This is another example of
the need to 
check for extraneous solutions
when expressions have been squared.

Note that
the solution runs into trouble
when
$\sin^2(x) = C$,
since the denominator is
$\sin^2(x)(\sin^2(x)-C)$.

The solution, slightly simplified,
is
$ y' 
= \frac1{\sin(x)} \sqrt{\frac{C}{\sin^2(x) - C}}
$.

Incidently,
Wolfy says that
(the second and third lines are
my simplification)

$\begin{array}\\
\int \frac1{\sin(x)}\sqrt{\frac{C}{\sin^2(x) - C}} dx 
&= (-C)^{-3/2}(C \sqrt{\frac{-C}{C - sin^2(x)}} \sqrt{\sin^2(x) - C}
 \tanh^{-1}\left(\frac{ \sqrt{-2C} cos(x)}{\sqrt{-2 C - cos(2 x) + 1}}\right)\\
&= (-C)^{-3/2}(C^{3/2}
 \tanh^{-1}\left(\frac{ \sqrt{-2C} cos(x)}{\sqrt{-2 C - cos(2 x) + 1}}\right)\\
&= (-1)^{-3/2}( \tanh^{-1}\left(\frac{ \sqrt{-2C} cos(x)}{\sqrt{-2 C - cos(2 x) + 1}}\right)\\
\end{array} 
$

So it seems that
that integral can be done,
though I don't trust Wolfy's result
because of the
complex values introduced.

I am too lazy
to check it or
try to integrate it myself.